# C++ stack implementation, not reserving memory in function

Tags: c++, memory-management, stack

Hello I want to write stack implementation, unfortunately something went wrong

## CPP FILE

```
  Node* head=0;

std::cout << "front insertion" << std::endl;
addBeg(head, 1);
std::cout<<head<<std::endl;
```

## HEADER FILE

```
class Node
{public:
    int value;
    class Node *next_el;
    Node(int value){ this->value=value;next_el=NULL;}
};

void addBeg(Node *head, int value){
head=new Node(value); //even that doesn't work!?
}
```

I would really like to know why "head" in main is still NULL value;
What do I do wrong?

Comment: You're assigning the newed value to a copy of the pointer.

Comment: I was told not to change CPP file so i cannot change passed parameter like head to &head.

Comment: Sorry, I just pressed the wrong button and removed a comment, that I wanted to upvote :-(
The comment suggested to use: `*head = Node(value)` which makes a lot of sense. Besides that, why don't use `std::list`?

Comment: @KaiPetzke I actually deleted the comment. I realized my mistake afterwards. The pointer is null, that would assign a value to a null pointer, this will crash. [Runtime error occurs](http://ideone.com/us9QrS)

Comment: @Kai because i have to do it that way;)
Yes the last idea gives Segfault.

Comment: @Borgleader You are right.

Comment: @Beta Wrong. it's fixable. I just realized how, but this is homework so I'm not going to give the answer. I will say this however, *reference*.

Comment: @Borgleader: your comment and my retraction/answer passed in the ether.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by changing the header, but it's underhanded:

```
void addBeg(Node * &head, int value){
  head=new Node(value); // now it works
}
```

Both versions are invoked the same way in the code. Changing a function this way (to take an argument by reference instead of by value) could really trip up users, but I guess in this case it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you for your time gentlemans. I found the solution, ecact as Beta's.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write your own linked list implementation (instead of just using, what is already there, like std::list), I recommend, that you take a look, first, about how linked lists work in C (not C++). A tutorial can be found here for example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24684/How-to-create-Linked-list-using-C-C

Once you have it working in C, you can try to write a C++ "wrapper" around it as a class or template. Other than that, your question is not really precise enough to know, how exactly your list should work.

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying pointer value only inside the addBeg() function, but you want to change value of the variable. Reminds me when i had similar problem and my teacher said "If it doesn't work, add asterisks"

So here it is:

```
class Node
{public:
    int value;
    class Node *next_el;
    Node(int value){ this->value=value;next_el=NULL;}
};

void addBeg(Node **head, int value){
*head=new Node(value); //even that doesn't work!?
}

Node* head=0;
std::cout << "front insertion" << std::endl;
addBeg(&head, 1);//notice &
std::cout<<head<<std::endl;
```

The other solution would be to use reference as shown in @Beta's answer